# Here api batch geocoding stays accepted

Tags: geocoding, here-api

We have recently implemented the here api to batch geocode addresses so we can create a route for shipments for our customer. All seems well, however when the address list containt a Belgian address, the batch gets accepted but it stays stuck on the accepted status and never seems to finish.The same call without an address in belgium (all dutch addresses) will work and give results after a little time.

Is there a trick to getting addresses in belgium to geocode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most probably a coincidence.

Note that this is a batching system having a queue to process jobs, so in rare cases jobs might queue up and take a while.

If the Geocoder cannot match any of the addresses, it will tell you so in the response.